# Trying to write TBitmaps to AVI file and getting only black frames (all zero data)

Tags: delphi, bitmap, getdibits, tbitmap, createdibsection

I have a Delphi application that reads JPEG frames from a file and writes them to an AVI file.  Each JPEG frame is decoded to a TBitmap object and then written to an output AVI file using the services provided by the Windows API DLL for AVI operations (AVIFIL32.DLL), via the Delphi 6 VFW.PAS unit.

The problem is I am ending up with all black frames in the output file.  I know the TBitmaps that I am using as the source before calling AVIStreamWrite() has valid data because I have written them to disk with the TBitmap.SaveToFile() method and the source image looks fine.  But I still end up with black frames.  There is something wrong with the way I am getting the bits from the TBitmap because the pointer returned by GetDIBBits() shows all zereos if I inspect the memory area it is pointing to.

Below is my code.  What am I doing wrong?  Also, if I try to free the first pBits returned by CreateDIBSection() I get an access violation.  Is that normal or is there some proper way to release it?

```
// aryBytes contains a JPEG frame as a Byte array.

/*
    Gets the next JPEG frame from a video input file and writes it to
    the output AVI file (stream).

    If the HRESULT from the desired operation is a failure code a
    formatted Exception will be raised.
*/
procedure makeAviCallWithJPEGFrame(
                fullVideoInFilename: string;
                const aryBytes: TDynamicByteArray;
                theAviMaker: TAviWriterWithCompression);
var
    hr: HRESULT;
    bmi: TBitmapInfo;
    pImg: PJpegDecode;
    jpegDecodeErr: TJpegDecodeError;
    hbm: HBITMAP;
    pBits, pBits2: Pointer;
    theBitmap: Graphics.TBitmap;
    iNumScanLinesCopied: integer;
    numBytesInBitmap: Integer;
begin
    if not Assigned(theAviMaker) then
        raise Exception.Create('(makeAviCallWithJPEGFrame) The AVI maker is unassigned.');

    pImg        := nil;
    pBits       := nil;
    pBits2      := nil;
    hbm         := 0;
    theBitmap   := nil;

    try
        jpegDecodeErr := JpegDecode(@aryBytes[0], Length(aryBytes), pImg);

        if jpegDecodeErr <> JPEG_SUCCESS then
            raise Exception.Create('(makeAviCallWithJPEGFrame) The bitmap failed to decode with error code: ' + IntToStr(Ord(jpegDecodeErr)));

        // Get the DIB bits.
        // theBitmap.SaveToFile('c:\temp\robomoviemaker.bmp');

        if not Assigned(pImg) then
            raise Exception.Create('(makeAviCallWithJPEGFrame) The bitmap decoded from the first JPEG frame in the video file is unassigned: ' + fullVideoInFilename);

        pImg^.ToBMI(bmi);

        theBitmap := pImg.ToBitmap;
//  This always shows a valid image so I know the bitmap contains image data.
// theBitmap.SaveToFile('c:\temp\test-bitmap.bmp');
        // Now create a DIB section.
        hbm := CreateDIBSection(theBitmap.Handle, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, pBits, 0, 0);

        if hbm = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER then
            raise Exception.Create('(makeAviCallWithJPEGFrame) One of the parameters passed to CreateDIBSection is invalid.');

        if hbm = 0 then
            raise Exception.Create('(makeAviCallWithJPEGFrame) The call to CreateDIBSection failed.');

        // Height may be negative to indicate orientation so we
        //  take the absolute value of it.

        // Allocate memory to receive the bits.
        numBytesInBitmap :=
            Abs(bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight)
            * Abs(bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth)
            * bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount;

        numBytesInBitmap := numBytesInBitmap div 8;

        pBits2 := AllocMem(numBytesInBitmap);

        if not Assigned(pBits2) then
            hr := LongInt(AVIERR_MEMORY)
        else
        begin
            // Get the DIB bits first.
            iNumScanLinesCopied :=
            // hr :=
                GetDIBits(
                    theBitmap.Canvas.Handle,
                    theBitmap.Handle,
                    0,
                    Abs(bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight),
                    pBits2,
                    bmi, // @pVidInfoHdr.bmiHeader^,
                    DIB_RGB_COLORS);

            if iNumScanLinesCopied <= 0 then
                // Flag it as internal error.
                hr := LongInt(AVIERR_INTERNAL)
            else
                // Add the bitmap to the output AVI file.
                hr := theAviMaker.addVideoFrame(hbm);
        end; // if not Assigned(pBits2) then

        checkAviResult('TfrmMain_moviemaker_.cmdTestClick', hr, 'Error during add video frame call');
    finally
        if Assigned(pBits2) then
            FreeMem(pBits2);

        if Assigned(pImg) then
        begin
            pImg^.Free;
            pImg := nil;
        end;

        if Assigned(theBitmap) then
            FreeAndNil(theBitmap);

        if hbm > 0 then
            DeleteObject(hbm);
    end; // try (2)
end;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you verified that all the bmi field values look reasonable before your call to GetDIBits?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError.  I believe so: biSize: 40, biWidth: 320, biHeight: -240, biPlanes: 1, biBitCount: 32.  All the rest are zero.  biSizeImage is also 0 but the MSDN docs say that's fine for RGB.  As a test I did set biSizeImage to (abs(biHeight) * biWidth * biBitCount) div 8) and that didn't help.  Also, GetDIBits() returns 240, which is the correct number of scan lines it should process.  It feels almost like the "shadow buffer" problem I had with a DirectShow filter where I was accessing the bitmap in a way that caused a new empty bitmap to be created each time.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - I just tried setting the TBitmap's PixelFormat to pf32Bit and that didn't help.  Last time I forgot to do that it caused a new empty bitmap to be created each time I accessed the ScanLine property.  Didn't help this time.  I know something's wrong with the bits pointers I'm getting back.  Not only because they point to an all-zero memory area, but also because I tried overwriting th bit pointer's memory area with a constant and the values didn't actually write to the memory area.  It still showed all zeroes after the FillChar() when I inspected it in the debugger.